# Fastest way to find sum of column from table2 and show it with table1

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-workbench, query-optimization

I have two table,

```
table1
=======================================
pid    pname           coldate      col4
---------------------------------------
1      Tesitng Name1   2019-01-01    self
2      Tesitng Name2   2020-01-01    self
3      Tesitng Name3   2020-03-01    self2
4      Tesitng Name4   2020-04-04    self2
5      Tesitng Name5   2020-04-05    self3
```

in table1 pid have unique key

```
table2 //which have more than 600k rows
=======================================
billid   rate            pid
---------------------------------------
1        30               1
2        50               1
3        40               1
4        20               2
5        60               2
6        10               3
```

///In table2 billid have unique key

I try to show all rows of table1 with sum of rate column of table2 where table1.pid=table2.pid

Result shoul be like this

```
   table1
    =======================================================
    pid    pname           coldate       col4     total
    -------------------------------------------------------
    1      Tesitng Name1   2019-01-01    self      120
    2      Tesitng Name2   2020-01-01    self       80
```

I am using this query and its working for me but it taking to much time plesae tell me the fastest way

```
SELECT t1.*,
          (SELECT sum(rate) as total FROM table2 where pid=t1.pid) as total
          FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-0' AND '2020-04-01'
          AND t1.col4 Like 'self' ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

I am using php with mysql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*
    , ttl.total
FROM table1 t1 
    inner join 
        (SELECT pid, sum(rate) as total 
        FROM table2 
        GROUP BY pid) as ttl
            on ttl.pid=t1.pid
WHERE 
    t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

Comment: thanks for your attention I am trying your answer :)

Comment: There's no pid in ttl

Comment: there is no pid because we are not selected pid with table 2

Comment: It have one problem, it does't show table1 row which which pid is not in table2

Answer (score 0):

You approach using a correlated subquery is quite good, and possibly the fastest method.

For performance, you want an index on `table2(pid, rate)`.

You also might consider an index on `table1(col4, coldate, pid)`, and rewrite the condition on `col4` to use an explicit equality instead of a pattern match without wildcard (although, possibly, the database did optimize that already):

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    (SELECT sum(rate) as total FROM table2 where pid=t1.pid) as total
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE 
    t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

In last resort, you can also enumerate all columns from `table1` in the `SELECT`  clause, and add them to the index, in hope that it will make it *covering* - `table1(col4, coldate, pid, name)`:

```
SELECT 
    t1.pid,
    t1.name,
    t1.coldate,
    t1.col4,
    (SELECT sum(rate) as total FROM table2 where pid=t1.pid) as total
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE 
    t1.coldate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-04-01'
    AND t1.col4 = 'self' 
ORDER BY t1.pid DESC;
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, but this query is taking to much time, i am waiting for more answer :)

Comment: sorry but its taking same time :(

Comment: @SmartDeveloper: do you have the two recommended indexes in place?

Comment: Am I missing something? Why does this require a correlated sub-query?